# convert Latex to RMD

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

My Rmarkdown return error when I'm trying to load the `graphicx` or `geometry` package with the following error :

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}
---

sometext


processing file: test.Rmd
output file: test.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I am trying to convert the following latex to rmarkdown with no success :(

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \Huge{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
          Data: 17/05/2013\\
          Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyfoot[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \Huge{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
          Data: 17/05/2013\\
          Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
%% add this if you want the fancy style also on the first page of a chapter:
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I'm on windows 10, using `R 4.2.3` and Texlive full distribution is already installed and I am able to compile the `.tex` example !

if I use the `.tex` directly in RMD I will get error like :

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \geometry{hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt}
  - \setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}

  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  - \fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
  - \fancyhead[C]{%
            \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
            \centering
            \Huge{TITLE} &
            \centering
            \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
            Data: 17/05/2013\\
            Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
            \hline
            \end{tabular}%
}
  - \fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
  - \fancyfoot[C]{%
            \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
            \centering
            \Huge{TITLE} &
            \centering
            \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
            Data: 17/05/2013\\
            Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
            \hline
            \end{tabular}%
}
classoption: demo
---


\chapter{Chapter title}
%% add this if you want the fancy style also on the first page of a chapter:
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-10]

Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 23, column 17
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: Another option you might consider instead of Rmd is using [Lyx](https://www.lyx.org/) with either [Sweave](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxWithRThroughSweave) or with [kntr](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/lyx/) or with [pgfSweave](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/10/how-to-start-using-pgfsweave-in-lyx-in-one-minute/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that rmarkdown already loads truckloads of packages before it even inserts your header-includes. You thus are no longer able to load them with the options you want.

As a workaround, you can

- just remove the `hyperref` package, as it is already loaded
- replace `\usepackage[...]{geometry}` with `\geometry{...}` to modify the options of the already loaded geometry package
- getting the `demo` option to `graphicx` is more tricky. Do you really need it? It will prevent all your images from showing up. If you really need it, you could force in on all packages with `classoption: demo`. Notice that this will pass the option to all loaded packages. If other packages also have this option, the results might change.
- if you actually want to replicate your latex document, you might also want to change the document class as `bookdown::pdf_document2` by default uses the `article` class which is very different then your `book` class.

---

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \geometry{hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt}
classoption: demo
---

sometext
```

The full document:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
documentclass: book
classoption: demo   
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{geometry}
  - \geometry{hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt}
  - \setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  - \fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
  - \fancyhead[C]{\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|} \hline\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &           \centering \Huge{TITLE} & \centering \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\ Data{:} 17/05/2013\\  Rev. 0}\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}}
  - \fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
  - \fancyfoot[C]{\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|} \hline \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} & \centering \Huge{TITLE} & \centering \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\ Data{:} 17/05/2013\\ Rev. 0}\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}}
---


# Chapter title
\thispagestyle{fancy}
## Section title
\lipsum[1-10]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you please help me to convert the latex example to RMD ?

Comment: basically I would like to have a table as it is in the latex template as header in all of the pages of my RMD report

Comment: @Haribo You can use the latex  code in rmarkdown

Comment: I have updated the question !
I'm getting the error saying : `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
`

Comment: @Haribo everything before `\begin{document}` needs to go into your header-includes. In the document body it is too late. Then you don't use `\begin{document}...\end{document}` in rmarkdown, it does this automatically. And if you want to use chapters, you must change the class, the rmarkdown template you choose uses the `article` class which does not have chapters.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but seems that I'm really bad at this :( ! I have updated the error !

Comment: @Haribo Either remove the line breaks in your header-includes or prefix all lines with `-`, not just the first line of a macro

Comment: thanks a lot ! It is getting closer ! If I add the `title` in yaml how this header can be appear in the tile page and the contents page as well ?

Comment: @Haribo If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: I posted as new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762639/table-as-header-on-all-the-pages-in-rmd-document