# Table as header on all the pages in RMD document

Tags: r, templates, latex, r-markdown, knitr

would like to customize the title page of my RMD template to have a table as header on every pages as the screenshot below :

[image]
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762203/convert-latex-to-rmd/75762232?noredirect=1#comment133648802_75762232) solution somhow needs a customization which specially on title page I don't know how to do it !

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
documentclass: book
classoption: demo   
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{geometry}
  - \geometry{hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt}
  - \setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  - \fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
  - \fancyhead[C]{\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|} \hline\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &           \centering \Huge{TITLE} & \centering \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\ Data{:} 17/05/2013\\  Rev. 0}\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}}
  - \fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
  - \fancyfoot[C]{\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|} \hline \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} & \centering \Huge{TITLE} & \centering \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\ Data{:} 17/05/2013\\ Rev. 0}\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}}
---


# Chapter title
\thispagestyle{fancy}
## Section title
\lipsum[1-10]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [manual for the fancyhdr LaTeX package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) gives the solution (see page 13): add `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` to the list of header-includes. It also means you no longer need `\thispagestyle{fancy}` in the document body.

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
documentclass: book
classoption: demo   
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{geometry}
  - \geometry{hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt}
  - \setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancypagestyle{plain}{}
  - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  - \fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
  - \fancyhead[C]{\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|} \hline\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &           \centering \Huge{TITLE} & \centering \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\ Data{:} 17/05/2013\\  Rev. 0}\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}}
  - \fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
  - \fancyfoot[C]{\begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|} \hline \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} & \centering \Huge{TITLE} & \centering \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\ Data{:} 17/05/2013\\ Rev. 0}\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}}
---

# Chapter title
## Section title
\lipsum[1-10]
```